# When I try to execute the stored procedure in ColdFusion, then not all of the information is returned

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to execute the stored procedure in ColdFusion, then not all of the information is returned.

- I'm running ColdFusion 9.0.1 w/ Hot Fix 2.
- I'm working with SQL Server 2008 r2.
- I'm limited to stored procedure calls.
- I can execute a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio to return a single record either in as a variable or as a select statement. The complete record is returned.
- The data stored in the database is 36539 characters long.
- The data returned by ColdFusion from a resultset is 32000 characters long.
- The data returned by ColdFusion from a cf_sql_varchar is 4000 characters long.
- The data returned by ColdFusion from a cf_sql_longvarchar is 4000 characters long.
- The data returned by ColdFusion from a cf_sql_text is 4000 characters long.
- The data returned by ColdFusion from a cf_sql_text is 4000 characters long.

Any ideas on how I can get my data with a ColdFusion stored procedure call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1) Log in to your ColdFusion administrator

2) Click on "Data Sources" on the navigation menu (under Data & Services)

3) Click on your data source

4) Click on the "Show Advanced Settings" button at the bottom of the page

5) Check the box next to "CLOB"

I would bet the "Buffer" values in the next boxes are "4000" on your server.

The default is "64000", which may be a clue than I am off base here.

Comment: #5 did the trick. Resultset is now returning the complete value.

The buffer was set to 64000.

Comment: It's worth noting that the output variable still maxes out at 4000. I'm happy with the resultset method.